# How to check the size of a h2 database?

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, h2

I have a question which I could not find answers to on the internet. I have much data stored in a h2 database. I use the h2 database in my Webservice, written in Java Hibernate and Angular.

I have around 30000 rows of data and I do not know how to start getting the size of it. The h2 files I found didn't contain information about it either.

I have 6 tables and 30.000 data rows in general.

So, how can I calculate the size of my h2 database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the size of the database file you can execute the following query:

```sql
SELECT `VALUE` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.FILE_SIZE';
```

If your database is in the legacy PageStore format, you need to execute another query instead:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT CAST(`VALUE` AS BIGINT) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.PAGE_COUNT')
    *
    (SELECT CAST(`VALUE` AS INTEGER) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.PAGE_SIZE')
```

You can also determine the size of some table (excluding its indexes) with `DISK_SPACE_USED` function:

```sql
CALL DISK_SPACE_USED('TABLE_NAME');
```

The name of the table should be specified as a string.

This function is supported by the legacy PageStore engine, and it is also supported by default MVStore engine, but only since version 1.4.198, in older 1.4.* versions it returns 0. The returned value also does not include the size occupied by LOBs.

With the default MVStore engine you can also get the space occupied by currently used pages in the database file:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT CAST(`VALUE` AS BIGINT) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.PAGE_COUNT_LIVE')
    *
    (SELECT CAST(`VALUE` AS INTEGER) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.PAGE_SIZE')
```

Comment: This is valid SQL for MVStore in H2 2.0.204: 
`SELECT SETTING_VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE SETTING_NAME = 'info.FILE_SIZE';`